# working with StreamReader and text files

Tags: c#

I want to put a test loop on the button click event. When I click this button, it reads the contents of the text file, but I want it to pop up an error message showing “unable to read file”, if it’s not a text file....
This is my code

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text);
    richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
}
```

How can I go about it?

Comment: Do you mean show an error if the text file doesn't exist? In which case you need to first check if the file exists before creating a new streamreader. Generally, your question isn't very understandable.

Comment: no i mean if the file is not readable coz if i run the button its shows the contents of the text file in the richtextbox but if i try to open a doc file it can not show the contents on the richtextbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best code, but it should work. Ideally you would separate the logic into two methods, a function to check the file exists and is a text file (returning a bool), another to read the contents if the check function returned true and populate the textbox with the contents.

EDIT: This is better:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = textBox1.Text;
        bool FileValid = ValidateFile(filePath);

        if (!IsFileValid)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("File {0} does not exist or is not a text file", filePath));
        }
        else
        {
            textbox2.Text = GetFileContents(filePath);
        }
    }

    private bool IsFileValid(string filePath)
    {
        bool IsValid = true;

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            IsValid = false;
        }
        else if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLower() != ".txt")
        {
            IsValid = false;
        }

        return IsValid;
    }

    private string GetFileContents(string filePath)
    {
        string fileContent = string.Empty;

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return fileContent;
    }
```

Comment: sorry dude i made a mistake witht he code i wanted to write stramreader i just edit the code

Comment: Fixed errors and tidied up code. You will need to add the System.IO namespace in your code as Oliver states.

Answer (score 2):

A few if-statements and the namespace `System.IO` will do it

```
string filename = textBox1.Text;
if (Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLower()) == ".txt") {
    if (File.Exists(filename)) {
        // Process the file here
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("The file does not exist");
    }
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("Not a text file");
}
```